# How can i extract fields from a class object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, class

I have a class which having some properties

```
public class SendData
{
public int MerchantID{get; set;}
public string Name{get; set;}
public int Age{get; set;}
}
```

And on button click and initializing user data to the object of this class.

```
button_click()
{
SendData senddata = new SendData();

senddata.MerchantID = Convert.ToInt32(txtMerchantid.Text);
senddata.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
senddata.Name= txtName.Text;

Webservice1.ReceiveDataService serviceObj = new Webservice1.ReceiveDataService();

public bool result = serviceObj.UpdateData(senddata); // calling web service
if(result) //Here is the scenario
lblresult.Text="Updated";
else
lblresult.Text="Operation unsuccessful";
}
```

Now how can i read all the fields from this object on the webservice method?

My webmethod:

```
public bool updatedata()//How to pass that object here
{
 //How can i get those three values in three separate fields in this method like.
 string name =""; //that name from UI;
 int id = ;//Id from UI
 int age= ;//Age from UI 
 //All the field need to be stored in database those coding will come here.
 return true;
}
```

Its quite simple but please help me and also u can suggest me some best and alternate way to achieve.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a parameter of type `SendData`, This type should be present in web service application and accessible to the consuming application.

```
public bool updatedata(SendData sendDate)//How to pass that object here
{
    //How can i get those three values in three separate fields in this method like.
    string name =""; //that name from UI;
    int id = ;//Id from UI
    int age= ;//Age from UI 
}
```

Comment: yes So I have created one mirror image of the same class here in web service but still am not able to complete it. And it throwing error pleas help me to write the function clearly

Comment: What error? You only need to declare it in Web Service end, If you want on both end which I think is not required then you can put them in different namespaces to differentiate them.

Answer (score -1):

We should add xmlInclude class before the web method so that the Class get exposed to the Client.

```
[WebMethod]    
[XmlInclude(typeof(Class_Name))]
public bool updatedata(Class_Name ObjectName)
{
string name =ObjectName.Name;
int id = ObjectName.ID;
int age= ObjectName.Age;
//Here the code for database storage etc., etc., and return the value...
return true;
}

Client has to create the proxy class and pass the object to this web service to do the functionalities.
```

([Can't send object to SOAP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783419/cant-send-object-to-soap-web-service))

Once again thank you all.